# Возможность добавлять видео у пользователя

Tags: java, android, видео, youtube

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии пользователя на иконку “Добавить видео”, создавался диалог, в который он может вставить заранее скопированную ссылку(с youtube), после чего нажимая кнопку “ok” будет загружать страницу которую ввёл пользователь(youtube) и оттуда выдирать ID видео. Храниться всё будет примерно в таком элементе `<meta itemprop=“videoId” content=“lWHKaK7Ql3k”>`. Искать ID посоветовали при помощи JSOUP. После того как получаем ID, пробуем получать картинку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Диалог создал:

```
private void showAddVideoDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Добавить видео");
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout_add_video, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
    final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.edt_videoUrl);
    builder.setView(viewInflated);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Отмена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно сгенерировать картинку с добавленного видео и добавить её в список, как показано на скриншоте.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "картинкой этого видео"? Какой именно кадр?

Comment: @metalurgus не имеет значение, основная идея показать пользователю, что его видео успешно добавилось.

Comment: Вы можете сгенерировать превью для видео тольк ,если это видео сохранено локально на дивайсе. Поэтому вам надо либо разрешать выбирать видео только с устройства, либо же генерировать изображения на каком-то сервере. На устройстве сгенерировать не получится.

Comment: @metalurgus то есть, если пользователь захочет добавить ссылку с ютуба, мне придётся это видео генерировать на сервере? Разве оно не случвйным кадром "падает"?

Comment: Тем более про ютуб - вы же говорили про ссылку на видео, а не на HTML-страницу с видео? YouTube вам не даст прямых ссылок на видео.

Comment: @metalurgus мне кажется вы не поняли моего вопроса. Пользователь копирует ссылку с ютуба - потом открывая диалог в моем приложении, нажимает на поле ввода - после чего нажимает Insert и ok.
И это видео добавляется картинкой как изображено выше, но просматривать и т д и т п в самом ютубе. Даже просто пускай картинкой там пока висит, не обязательно просматривать.

Comment: Наверно не я не понял, а вы его задали не так. Потому, что Превью видео-файла на самом деле можно получить, но только локально.

Comment: @metalurgus мне не надо локально. Мне нужно конкретно по ссылке с youtube как в этом приложении, у них то это как то получилось.

Comment: в каком? В любом случае, скорее всего, они получают изображение со своего сервера. Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал вашим настоящим интересам, чтобы никто не угадывал, что же вы все-таки подразумеваете.

Comment: @metalurgus а как же получение через "metadata"? Если не ошибаюсь возможно таким путём пойти.

Comment: metadata есть у видео-файла. Ссылка на youtube - это не видео-файл. Это даже не ссылка на видео-файл.

Comment: @metalurgus с её помощью я могу реализовать задуманное?

Comment: с помощью metadata? Вообще-то нет. Она не содержит никаких Preview

Comment: @metalurgus почему? разве к такому типу нельзя преобразовать? 
http://img.youtube.com/vi/Rxo0Upfz48Q/0.jpg

Comment: Ок, я возможно нашел вам способ. Посмотрев исходный код страницы с видео, я нашел ссылку на изображение вида `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OOIk_AmrNDM/hqdefault.jpg`, где `OOIk_AmrNDM` - ID видео. То есть, если вместо `%s` в ссылку `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/%s/hqdefault.jpg` вставить айдишник видео, то получите ссылку на картинку. Ссылка на видео выглядит вот так: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOIk_AmrNDM

Comment: Почти синхронно!)
Только вот и само затруднение, как реализовать подобное в моём коде, не очень представляю, возможно есть пример?

Comment: Вы можете попробовать использовать Youtube API Для этого. Он должен позволять такое сделать. Если не хотите, можете загружить HTML-страницу по ссылке, которую ввел пользователь, и оттуда выдирать ID видео. Он хранится в таком элементе: `<meta itemprop="videoId" content="lWHKaK7Ql3k">`. Найти его можно, например, при помощи `JSOUP`. А получив ID видео, картинку получить уже просто.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем набрел на что то следующее (реализовано для youtube).

```
String youtubeUrl = "";

private void uploadImageFromLink() {
    Document videoPage = Jsoup.connect(youtubeUrl).get();

    Element videoIdMeta = videoPage.select("div[itemtype=http://schema.org/VideoObject] meta[itemprop=videoId]").first();
    if (videoIdMeta == null) {
        // Unable to determine videoId ...
    } else {
        String videoId = videoIdMeta.attr("content");

        // Fetch video image
        String videoImageUrl = String.format("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/%s/hqdefault.jpg", videoId);
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                .connect(videoImageUrl)
                .ignoreContentType(true) // Needed for fetching image
                .execute();

        // Load image for later use
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.bodyAsBytes()));
    }
}
```

Думаю также пригодиться:

- [Как получать картинку с помощью JSOUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484492/how-to-get-a-form-captcha-image-with-jsoup/34491304#34491304)
- [Как получать ID-шник видео с помощью JSOUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007597/extract-a-youtube-video-url-from-a-site-url-using-jsoup/39742707#39742707)
- [Загружать картинки с помощью url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url/5776903#5776903)
- [BitmapFactory javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)
- [Простенький пример с официального сайта, там уже самим можно вдоволь полазить](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

Возможно кто то знает как можно сделать подобное, не используя дополнительных библиотек? Буду только рад!

Answer (score 0):

Есть встроенная утилита извлечения *Thumbnail* из видео, типа:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
Bitmap thumbBitmap=null;
try {
    retriever.setDataSource(videoUri.getPath());
    thumbBitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(-1);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting frame for video=" + videoUri.getPath(), ex);
}
```